# SP.ClientContext.get_current() returning undefined objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get some information about the current context through the sharepoint javascript object model and am getting annoying errors.

```
$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadConstants, "sp.js"); });

function loadConstants() {

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var site = ctx.get_site();
IPC_siteUrl = site.get_url();
IPC_siteId = site.get_id();

var web = ctx.get_web();
}
```

This is what im calling in a javascript file in our core javascript file, and when i try to call "ctx.get_site()" I am getting errors through the dev console on ie8.

The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Im not sure why this is happening as im following Microsofts directions.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The SharePoint Client Side Object Model works a bit different as on the server side. Before you can use an object you must first load it and then you must execute a query to retrieve the object.

In [this blogpost](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-for.html) you can find a description how to use it.

```
$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadConstants, "sp.js"); });

function loadConstants() {

var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

this.site = ctx.get_site();
ctx.load(this.site );
this.web = ctx.get_web();
ctx.load(this.web);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));


}

function onSuccess(sender, args) {
   IPC_siteUrl = this.site.get_url();
   IPC_siteId = this.site.get_id();
}
funtion onFail(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you need the `new` keyword on `get_current()`

Or if you do, it's just `new SP.ClientContext();` I think

Comment: With or without I get the same error.

Comment: Just did a quick edit, try my second suggestion.

Comment: Same for that one too

Comment: Balls. If you go to your Javascript console, does typing 'SP' come back with anything?

Comment: Yea, {...} but thats it

Comment: That's good, that means the SP namespace is available. Try the ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded outside of the jquery load block...

Comment: Thats actually the first line of my code block that I put into my question.

Comment: Aye, I'm wondering if jQuery is conflicting in some weird way (I've not seen this before, but jQuery versions might be doing odd things).

Comment: The use of the keyword "new" is needed. If you try only  var context = SP.ClientContext().get_current(); we get the Object doesn't support property or method 'set_formDigestHandlingEnabled'.

Answer (score 2):

Try it, its working :

```
var clientContext;

$(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', execOperation);
    });

function execOperation() {
        try {
            clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();                   
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    }
```